# htaccess: корневую директорию заменить другой

Tags: .htaccess, apache

У нас 1 сайт `site1.ru`, и есть домен `site2.ru`, который является синонимом первого домена. Т.е, когда заходишь на `site2.ru`, то видишь тоже самое, что и на `site1.ru`.

Нужно сделать так, чтобы для при переходе по `site2.ru`, покатывался не корень сайта (т.е. `/index.php`), а по умолчанию подключалась папка `/dev/index.php`, но при этом, чтобы этот путь в адресной строке не отображался (т.е, только должен быть `site2.ru`).

Подскажите пожалуйста, как это сделать через htaccess?

Comment: Кажись `htaccess` тут не причем. За это отвечает сервер или в корне `apache`, `unix` и т.д..

Comment: @And htaccess это и есть конфигурационный файл веб-сервера apache

Comment: `htaccess` - это всего лишь файл который лежит в корне или в папке, который нужен для оптимизации сайта, он ничего не знает о другом домене или каталоге. Вам же нужно подменить один каталог другим, как вы себе представляете, чтобы через `htaccess` это сделать? Ко всему еще и на разных доменах. Странный вы какой-то. Тут как минимум нужно делать маршруты от одного сервера к другому и связывать один сайт с другим, подменяя выбранным.

Comment: @And 
1) .htaccess это конфигурационный файл веб-сервера Apache.
2) Домена разные. Но второй домен является синонимом первого.
3) В .htaccess можно ставить условия в зависимости от домена которого зашли, директории т .д. Например: RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} site2.com [NC, OR]   RewriteCond $1 !^(dev) ...